# How to set pyenv python for reticulate

Tags: r

I'm using 1.10 version of reticulate package ( R version is 3.5.1) and I want to configure it to use pyenv python (path is /Users/name/.pyenv/versions/hak/bin/python). Running py_config() won't show me this python as available:

```
    python:         /usr/bin/python
    libpython:      
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.
    framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.dylib
    pythonhome:     
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.
    framework/Versions/2.7:/System/Library

    /Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
    version:        2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07)  
    [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)]
    numpy:          /System/ Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy
    numpy_version:  1.8.0

    python versions found: 
     /usr/bin/python
     /usr/local/bin/python
     /usr/local/bin/python3
```

Because my pyenv python isnt available I set RETICULATE_PYTHON env variable on mentioned path. But now i get the error
Error in initialize_python(required_module, use_environment) :

```
    Python shared library 
    '/Users/name/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/libpython3.6.dylib' 
    not found, Python bindings not loaded.
```

Does anybody know how to solve this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

pyenv doesn't build pythons with shareable libraries by default. to make sure it does either have the CONFIGURE_OPTIONS variable set or preface your `pyenv build $VERSION` commands as in the example below:

```
env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" pyenv install 3.7.5
```

see:
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/plugins/python-build/README.md#building-with---enable-shared)