# RStudio discovers Python pyenv installation, but I'm unable to run Python processes

Tags: python, r, macos, rstudio, pyenv

I'm trying to run Python in RStudio. I have installed Python 3.8.5 via pyenv, and created a virtual environment with pyenv virtualenv (which I call venv-Rstudio) in my RStudio project folder. Based on the instructions  given [here](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/versions.html#providing-hints), I think I have correctly managed to indicate to RStudio which Python environment to use:

```
>Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON="/Users/my_username/.pyenv/versions/venv-Rstudio/bin/python")
> py_discover_config()
python:         /Users/my_username/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/envs/venv-Rstudio/bin/python
libpython:      [NOT FOUND]
pythonhome:     /Users/my_username/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5:/Users/my_username/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5
version:        3.8.5 (default, Oct  1 2020, 21:50:37)  [Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)]
numpy:          /Users/my_username/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/envs/venv-Rstudio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.18.5
```

When trying to call Python, I get the following error:

```
> py_config()
Error: Python shared library not found, Python bindings not loaded.
Use reticulate::install_miniconda() if you'd like to install a Miniconda Python environment.
```

I suspect this has something to do with `libpython: [NOT FOUND]` seen above, but I have made sure libpython is installed in the venv-Rstudio virtual environment:

```
(venv-Rstudio) my_username@MBP15 Rstudio % pip list
Package                Version
---------------------- ---------
...
Keras                  2.4.3
Keras-Preprocessing    1.1.2
libpython              0.2
Markdown               3.2.2
multidict              4.7.6
numpy                  1.18.5
...
```

Any ideas what I might be missing and how to fix this? I'm running macOS 10.15.7 Catalina, RStudio 1.3 with R version 4.0.2.

Comment: What version of rstudio are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After posting my question, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54043607/8861903) appeared in the *Related* list, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59148437/8861903) by @nucholab solved my problem. In short, re-installing Python with pyenv using the following command enables shareable libraries:

```
env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" pyenv install 3.8.5
```

After that and re-creating my virtual environment (and for the record, installing numpy), loading Python in RStudio works as expected:

```
> py_config()
python:         /Users/my_username/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/envs/venv-Rstudio/bin/python
libpython:      /Users/my_username/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/lib/libpython3.8.dylib
pythonhome:     /Users/my_username/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5:/Users/andreas/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5
version:        3.8.5 (default, Oct  2 2020, 13:54:11)  [Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)]
numpy:          /Users/my_username/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/envs/venv-Rstudio/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.19.2
tensorflow:     [NOT FOUND]

NOTE: Python version was forced by RETICULATE_PYTHON
```